# How to get the value that is added as header in response from server to client (in reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added the headers in HttpContext in .NET web API. In the browser network, I can see the added header in the response. But in reactjs fetch function, its showing that added header as false while check response.headers.has. Why its showing false?

I have been developing web application with .NET web server and reactjs as client. I have tried with response.headers.has("key") which is showing false so not getting when trying with response.headers.get("key").

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Paging-Headers", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationMetadata));
var list= VehicleModelMapper.ToViewModelList(items.OrderBy(c => c.id).AsQueryable());
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);
```

Server Side (Added response header)
[image]

Browser Network response content
[image]

console.log at client side which is false even the header is added
[image]

[image]

I expect the value of added header in the response at client side which is reactjs. It is available in browser network but while consoling it after response received, its undefined. How to get the response added header in response?

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` that at the second `then` chained to `fetch` ?

Comment: @SultanH. The second `then` chained has only the response data which is JSONformat. No records of header information is available there.

Comment: Solved. @Gabriele Petrioli answer helped to find the solution.
I added the `exposedHeaders` in `EnableCors` so that added header is available at client side. 

`[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com, headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "Paging-Headers")]`